# Variant VCF: AD vs DP?

Tags: bioinformatics, variant

In my VCF file from GATK, I have the following definitions for `AD` and `DP`.

```
AD - Allelic depths for the ref and alt alleles in the order listed
DP - Approximate read depth (reads with MQ=255 or with bad mates are filtered
```

I don't understand the definitions, can anybody explain in a less technical way?

From what I can read, `AD` gives the number of reads spanning the reference and variant allele. But what does `DP` mean? This doesn't look like the total number of reads spanning a variant, so what is this? How does this different to `AD`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DP is the total number of read bases spanning a particular position. If you add up the different AD, you should get a number close to DP, the difference being merely in how the reads are filtered in either set of numbers.